# Pashto Language Support

Tags: software-installation, language-support

Is there a language pack for Pashto (Afghanistan) and how do I find it. It is not listed when I click on *Install/Remove Languages...*

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS - but going on a different box. Willing to install anything apart from WIndows. We have a Pashto speaker staying with us, learning English at the moment but not had internet/electricity before.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no Pashto language packs in the supported Ubuntu versions. The reason is that there are too few Pashto translations available to motivate the creation of language packs. A threshold is applied, and at least 5% of the translatable strings need to be translated.

You may want to join [this team](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-l10n-ps) and help improving the Pashto translation coverage in Ubuntu.

Comment: I am keen to get this process started. I clicked on the link shared above. If I understand it correctly there is a team working/planning to work on it. I haven't seen any progress. I emailed the group admin to ask for update and how I could contribute and hasn't heard anything back. Is there anyway I could start working on it? I just need a bit of guidance on how and what needs to be done. Thanks,

Comment: @Asim: That does not sound good. Can you please submit a question [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/) and describe the problem there just as you did here in your comment. Then I'll ask for the help needed to resolve the situation.